# how to set the path of live sass compiler to be the current path in VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass

I have below folder structure:

```
-src
  -component
    -button
      -button.js 
      -button.scss
    -dropdown
      -dropdown.js
      -dropdown.scss
```

When I use `live sass compiler` to `watch` the scss file, it generates 2 files like `button.css` and `button.css.map`, but it does not generate in the same path.

I want these generated files to be generated in the same path like below:

```
-src
  -component
    -button
      -button.js 
      -button.scss
      -button.css
      -button.css.map
    -dropdown
      -dropdown.js
      -dropdown.scss
      -dropdown.css
      -dropdown.css.map
```

In `setting.json`

```
{
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "eq-material-theme-icons",
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [

        {
            "format": "expanded",
            "extensionName": ".css",
            "savePath": "/dist/css"
        }
    ]
}
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `setting.json`

```
{
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "eq-material-theme-icons",
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [

        {
            "format": "expanded",
            "extensionName": ".css",
            "savePath": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the "savePath": null setting that allowed me to save to the local folder where the scss was saved.